# Generate a sub job

Tags: sql

PS: Added a new image to better describe what i would like to achieve

As I couldn't find a way to phase the question, therefore it limits the possibility that I could get a ''ready'' solution, pardon me if this is available.

I am self-learning SQL, and would hope to gain some valuable lessons and information on how to write something as the following, greatly appreciated!

Seeking to write lines that allows me to add a master job (eg. 05-16-00000)
in each master job, there will be other "jobs" so it should generate (eg. 05-16-0000 - 01 .. XX). How can I have it written in a way?

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWbvj.png)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWbvj.png)

Comment: Are you seeking assistance on how to setup your database, or how to do this via php? if the later, please post a structure for your database so we can see. I think that this questions needs some clarification before I / others can help you.

Comment: i would like to know how to setup the sql ..

Comment: So... Have you already created your database with these tables - or is the sql supposed to achieve this as well?

Comment: no yet, i just want to see how to have a sample..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: im looking to write everything off PHP / MYSQL (myphpadmin)..

Comment: Your description is somehow confusing. You expect child ids like "05-16-0000 - 01". You have job ids like "05-16-0000" and a child id like "01" in the table. Every row has a child id. What do want to achieve? Is there another table with master jobs? Do you want to add rows with empty child id? You should clarify the **expected result** in your question and setup an example **data source**.

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone, i've added a sample to what i want to achieve.

Comment: The "ideology" of a '' child '' id is that they act as an handler / id to retrieve data in future, for example like in search we just type 15-16-00002-02 and we can draw the data out with php.

I am not too sure how it should be written and thats why i am very much stuck between "table-ing" as well as due to limited php knowledge.

perhaps in php its something like, "mm . yy . ++ (master job) and check child, if null, set 01. if child 01, set 02"

Comment: I've added simple queries according to your given examples.

Answer (score 1):

Just hold an id for each record and if a row has a parent, you set a parent_job_id to the corresponding id. Rows with no parent have the parent_job_id set to `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE `dbname`.`job`
( `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `parent_job_id` BIGINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Get master jobs:

```
SELECT
  `job`.`id`,
  `job`.`description`,
  `job`.`parent_job_id`
FROM
  `testdb`.`job`
WHERE
  `job`.`parent_job_id` IS NULL
;
```

If you are looking for children of job 3 replace the `WHERE` clause with

```
WHERE `job`.`parent_job_id` = 3
```

As you show in your later added example you want to m:n link the table with itself. Create a table with parent and child IDs.

```
CREATE TABLE `dbname`.`job_parent_child`
( `parent_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `child_id`  BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`, `child_id`)
);
```

Same example - get all childs with parent job 3

```
SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`job` AS `child`
INNER JOIN `dbname`.`job_parent_child` AS `mn`
ON `child`.`id` = `mn`.`child_id`
WHERE `mn`.`parent_id` = 3
;
```

---

According to your last edit just select the job ids (and possibly other data if needed) from the table and iterate over the rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `JOB ID` FROM `jobs`;
```

Output the master job row of the html table. Then query with prepared statement

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `JOB ID` = ?;
```

Output all the rows. That's really all.

Comment: i have attached an image to describe what i want to achieve.. TIA!

Comment: Will try out and share what i am experiencing.. 

Thank you